# Javascript Not able call a function from callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

1. In the below code, while trying to call self.checkValue from the callback inside accounts.getValue, the function is not being called.
2. Also when trying to call self.checkValue() from setTimeout callback, getting error that checkValue is not defined.

```js
checkValue: function(resp) {
  var self = this;
  if (resp && !resp.value) {} else {
    if (getcount < 3) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        getcount++;
        // self.checkValue();
        accounts.getValue({
          callback: self.checkValue
        });
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
},

setValue: function() {
  var self = this;
  accounts.getValue({
    callback: self.checkValue
  });
},
```

Comment: Did you mean `checkValue = function`? Is this part of an object? This is a syntax error.

Comment: @SamR.the function declaration syntax is correct, have no issues while calling the checkvalue function from the callback of setValue function below

Comment: Why is this tagged with jQuery ? where is jQuery in the question ?